# How to remove scraped-on paint from finished wood

Tags: cleaning, wood

Some white-whicker deck furniture came into contact with some finished dark wood and left white streaks. They're resistant to simple abrasion. Is there any way to remove the paint without wrecking the finish? To be clear, the paint was dry when it rubbed off.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to clean.  I think you have dried white paint on some dark wood (of unknown type, finish and function) but I am not sure.

Comment: Hi Eamonn, Welcome to Lifehacks. See if the white is on raised portions of the darker wood. If so, can you carefully scrape those raised portions to remove the white marks with a sharp blade or scraper? Re-finish unsightly marks if they're visibly affected by your repair.

Comment: Finish is probably varnish or shellac of some description. It is a totally flat surface (the front of a dresser)

Comment: No matter what it was, my mother would first use some spit on her handkerchief to remove it. It didn't matter if it was paint on the car or food on my face. Nine times out of ten, it worked.

Comment: Please post a picture of the affected area, so we can see and understand better the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of different techniques to use. If the white marks from the wicker chair/table appear on a smooth finish darker surfaced hardwood, the white marks can be gently removed…

**chemically** with a mild solvent such as ethyl alcohol (Vodka, Gin, etc.) used on a rag or…

**mechanically** with *light* scraping using a sharp single-edge razor blade. Pull the blade over the marks while it's at a *nearly* vertical angle. A couple of "pulls" should be enough.

There's a better than average chance that your removal will slightly change the appearance of the dresser. Use a compatible colour furniture scratch remover to recover the original appearance of the dresser drawer.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

If it's paint (or a paint like substance) then perhaps "cut and polish" (like for cleaning up car paint) might work?

I'd recommend that you try it somewhere not visible first though. Just in case it damages the finish.